# Handsontable - Alternating Row Colours CSS Effecting Context Menu and Filters

Tags: css, handsontable

As per the instructions in the following link.

https://docs.handsontable.com/0.24.2/tutorial-styling.html#page-rows

I have added the following .css code to my website to allow alternating row colors in my Handsontable instance.

```
/* Every even row */
.ht_master tr:nth-of-type(even) > td {
  background-color: hsl(199, 100%, 95%);
}
```

However this has the unintended side effect of alternating the colors of the rows in the context menu and also filter menu. See screenshot below.

[image: Alternating Row Colors Error]

How can I correct my .css code to only alternate the row colors in the table itself and not the other menus?

Comment: Is there a demo somewhere we can see the markup generated for the table and the context menus?

Comment: If `.ht_master` is the table itself, then `.ht_master > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(even) > td` for a selector.

Comment: I actually got a response via email on this issue.... "Dropdown menu uses context menu under the hood. Both of them use the Handsontable instance as a core rendering engine, hence the problems with defining colors for only one of these plugins (and the main table, separately). You would need to add an additional selector to point at the main table, like in the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/4w3qnhv0/... I then created a fiddle to resolve my issue as follows... https://jsfiddle.net/JoshAdams/yxp192qL/22/. Feel free to post this as the answer if you like.